# How to rename all text objects by individual text content?

Tags: python, workflow, text-object

I have about 70 text objects in a scene that I neglected to rename as they were created, thus quickly making a disorganized mess in my outliner.

[image]

Is there some script or some other trick that will efficiently speed up renaming all text objects by the content of the text?

For example, if the content of the text object is "Blender" the object name should be Blender (or TXT_Blender if prefix is used). Although it would be useful for further organization, I am not too concerned with adding a prefix to the object names at the moment.

I know that *I could* copy/ paste each text to rename, but an automated solution would save a tremendous amount of time, considering the number of objects at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.type == 'FONT':
        ob.name = ob.data.body[:10]
```